# trouble with postgresql subquery

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, subquery

Here are my tables:

**table1:**

```
ID | data1 | data2
1  | xxx   | xxx 
2  | xxx   | xxx
```

**table2:**

```
ID | table1_id
20 | 1
21 | 1
25 | 2
26 | 2
```

**table3:**

```
ID | table2_id
30 | 20
31 | 21
32 | 25
33 | 26 <--
```

I have marked the relevant row by an arrow (table3: ID=33 | **table2_id=26**)

Now, I want the matching ID with data 1 and data 2 from table 1. In this case: **2**

I tried something ...

```
SELECT t1."ID"
FROM table AS t1

INNER JOIN table2 AS tb2
ON t1."ID" = t2."ID"

INNER JOIN table3 AS t3
ON t2."ID" = 26
```

... but it returns nothing. Have anybody a working subquery for me :)

Comment: I'm sure that the questions on SO used to be more intellectually challenging.

Comment: you've tagged this with multiple dbs, but in mysql `t1."ID"` and the like would NOT be a valid table/field identifier. it'd be `t1.ID` only, without the quotes. You could very well have syntax errors that your containing code is not checking for.

Comment: by the way, you join on the wrong field : `t1.Id = t2.table1_id` not `t2.id` for the first join. For the third, you probably mean `on t2.id = t3.table2_id`

Comment: @MarcB: `t1."ID"` **is** a standard compliant (valid) column identifier - even in MySQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cdd8e/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you join on the wrong fields

```
SELECT t1."ID"
FROM table AS t1

INNER JOIN table2 AS t2
   ON t1."ID" = t2.table1_id

INNER JOIN table3 AS t3
   ON t2."ID" = t3.table2_id
WHERE t3."ID" = 33
```

Comment: Plus, a typo in the table alias `tb2`. --> `t2`. And the now missing WHERE condition: `WHERE t3."ID" = 33`